# Displaying more text with one Text Input

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to display more than one text with `TextField` like so:

```
Susan            50
Bob              100
Michael          30
```

This is meant for leaderboard

Regards

Comment: you can use newline (\n) and tab (\t) characters to do just that. I recommend using a uniform-width font though.

Comment: Not exactly the best way to manage multiple instances of text, but you can always do what mfa here suggested and set `text.multiline` to true.

Comment: Thanks, you can tell me what's the best way to do that ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say for such a leaderboard you need two TextFields one adjacent to another, with identical `defaultTextFormat` properties, both set with `multiline=true; wordwrap=false`, and fill left one with names, and right one with scores. This way you can avoid the need of uniform-width fonts. An example:

```
public class Leaderboard extends Sprite {
    var namesTF:TextField;
    var scoresTF:TextField;
    var dtf:TextFormat;
    ...
        // this goes into the constructor
        dtf=new TextFormat(...);
        namesTF.defaultTextFormat=dtf;
        scoresTF.defaultTextFormat=dtf;
    ...
    public function displayScores(scores:Array):void {
        // scores are objects like {name:Susan,score=200}
        scores.sortOn("score",Array.NUMERIC+Array.DESCENDING);
        namesTF.text='';
        scores.text='';
        for each (var o:Object in scores) {
            namesTF.appendText(o.name+'\n');
            scoresTF.appendText(o.score.toString()+'\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Adjust the interface to the means your scores are recorded.

Comment: it keeps giving me errors:  Property name not found on String and there is no default value in that line: namesTF.appendText(o.name+'\n');

Comment: Sure enough. What kind of data do you transport into `displayScores()`? I thought that scores can be an Array of Objects, each having "name" and "score" properties. You seem to give it an Array of Strings instead. If so, you need to split them into name and score part.